# Creating a hard linked differential backup (trying with rsync)

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, shell-script, rsync

I am trying to create a script that creates *both* a snapshot backup *and* a differential backup, **but** with hard links instead of duplicated files. In other words:

- All unchanged files between the current snapshot backup and the previous snapshot are hard linked instead of being duplicated;
- All files on the differential backup are hard links to the files on the current snapshot.

Let me try to clarify. Be:

- `$SRC`: Source tree, original files to be backed up
- `$PREV`: Previous snapshot backup
- `$SNAPSHOT`: Current snapshot backup
- `$DIFF`: Differential backup (only changed files)
- `$RF`: rsync flags, like -aPhvv

I am able to create the hard linked snapshot with the following command:

```
rsync $RF --link-dest=$PREV $SRC $SNAPSHOT
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now I want to create another tree, `$DIFF`, with only the differences between `$SNAPSHOT` and `$PREV`.

I can do exactly that with the following command:

```
rsync $RF --compare-dest=$PREV $SNAPSHOT $DIFF
```

This also works fine and is very close to what I want to achieve. The only problem is that all the files that changed between `$PREV` and `$SNAPSHOT` are now duplicated on `$DIFF`, I would like them to be hard links to `$SNAPTSHOT` instead of plain copies.

From rsync perspective, what I want to do is this: after the snapshot is created, it becomes my new source tree, `$SNAPSHOT`. The destination is `$DIFF`. The base of comparison with the source is `$PREV`, so the argument `--compare-dest=$PREV` should take care of it. This, like the previous command, would copy only the files changed between previous snapshot and the current snapshot. Now, for the files to be copied, I want them to be compared to the files in $SNAPSHOT first and then, if existing there, linked against them instead of copied. This is what `--link-dest=$SNAPSHOT` does, and it also works. Both options work well individually, `compare-dest` creates a differential copy and `link-dest` creates a linked tree, but I want to mix both, in the way described above, which rsync **does not** permit.

If rsync permitted, this what I wanted to do:

```
# Create the snapshot backup:
myhost:~$ rsync $RF --link-dest=$PREV $SRC $SNAPSHOT
     // successful. output suppressed...

# Try to create the hard linked differential backup:
myhost:~$ rsync $RF --compare-dest=$PREV --link-dest=$SNAPSHOT $SNAPSHOT $DIFF
rsync: You may not mix --compare-dest, --copy-dest, and --link-dest.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1567) [client=3.1.2]
```

Any ideas on how to create the `$DIFF` tree in away that the files on this tree are all hardlinks to `$SNAPSHOT` ? Or other suggestions on how to achieve my goals with other linux commands?

Comment: You may find `rdiff-backup` and `rdiff-backup-fs` interesting. Or maybe BTRFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating `$DIFF` and `$SNAPSHOT` in the opposite order. First run

```
rsync $RF --compare-dest=$PREV $SRC $DIFF
```

Then create a hardlinked copy of the previous backup:

```
cp -al $PREV $SNAPSHOT
```

Finally, hardlink copy the changes onto there:

```
cp -al $DIFF $SNAPSHOT
```

Note: I haven't actually tested this, so can't guarantee it works.

Comment: In this variant `$SNAPSHOT` will contain files that absent in `$SRC` but present in `$PREV`, that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `--link-dest` option can be specified multiple times (since rsync version 2.6.4). It allows to create `$SNAPSHOT` in the following way:

```
rsync $RF --compare-dest=$PREV $SRC $DIFF

rsync $RF --link-dest=$PREV --link-dest=$DIFF $SRC $SNAPSHOT
```

NB: if the files content is the same but some **preserved** attributes are different (timestamp, permissions, ownership, etc) — the destination file will not be skipped or linked, but copied.

Regarding the timestamp attribute — the file (having the same content) will be copied when the timestamp is different even if **the timestamp is not preserved** but just used for files comparison (at least in rsync 3.1.1). Workaround: use `--size-only` or `--checksum` options.